# Github - We recommend upgrading to the latest Google Chrome or Firefox

Tags: github

There are multiple issues encounterd today while accessing #github
1. Not sure why #github saying "We recommend upgrading to the latest Google Chrome or Firefox". I am using current version of Chrome to log on to github
2. it get stuck at"fetching latest commit…"
3. it advise me "Use the switch context button in the upper left corner of this page to switch between your personal context (xxx) and organizations you are a member of" , I am unable to see switch context button on github dashboard
are these issue co-related ...

Comment: I think only your 2nd question is on topic for the site but you'd need to provide more information about the problem.

Comment: look like it was github issue ... today its working as normal